# How to duplicate tab?

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I looked around and I can't find a way to duplicate tabs. I know that Chrome has something like

```
chrome.tabs.duplicate(tab.id)
```

Is there anyway to do so on Puppeteer?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the code:

```
chrome.tabs.duplicate(
  tabId: number,
  callback?: function,
)
```

for details check this:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-duplicate